# How to parse this JSON file?

Tags: android, json, parsing

I have the following JSON file:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "creator": 16300398, 
      "description": "Discount txt Discount txt Discount txt\r\nShare\r\n-> Download    the app at http://drinsco.altervista.org/share.php?eid=204142299735343\r\n--> Login in your    Facebook account to use your discount!\r\nasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf    adsf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf    asdf asdf asdf asdfqwer qwer qwer qwer qwer qwer qwer asdf qwer asfdqwerasdf wqer", 
      "end_time": null, 
      "host": "Dave Luke", 
      "location": "Chipotle", 
      "name": "More Test Information", 
      "pic": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-   ash3/174629_204142299735343_644068191_s.jpg", 
      "pic_big": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash3/174629_204142299735343_644068191_n.jpg", 
      "pic_cover": null, 
      "pic_small": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash3/174629_204142299735343_644068191_t.jpg", 
      "pic_square": "https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-ash3/174629_204142299735343_644068191_q.jpg", 
      "start_time": "2013-07-11T16:00:00+0200", 
      "timezone": null, 

      "venue": {
        "latitude": 40.720457257566, 
        "longitude": -73.845858172784, 
        "city": "Forest Hills", 
        "state": "NY", 
        "country": "United States", 
        "id": 398225253590019, 
        "street": "70-30 Austin St.", 
        "zip": "11375"
      }
    }
  ]
  }
```

Which I need to transform into a single object like this:

```
 public class event {
     public int id;
     public String creator;
     public String description; 
     public String end_time; 
     public String host; 
     public String location; 
     public String name; 
     public String pic; 
     public String pic_big; 
     public String pic_cover; 
     public String pic_small; 
     public String pic_square; 
     public String start_time;
     public String timezone; 
     public String city; 
     public String state; 
     public String country; 
     public String street; 
     public String zip;
```

Thanks to Raghunandan, but the I do not understand the results I get:

[image]

```
private event getevent(String id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final evento e = new evento();
    e.id=id;
    String fqlQuery = "SELECT creator, description ,end_time, host,"
            + "location, name, pic, pic_big, pic_cover, pic_small, pic_square,start_time,"
            + "timezone, venue" + " FROM event WHERE eid=" + id;
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("q", fqlQuery);
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    Request request = new Request(session, "/fql", params, HttpMethod.GET,
            new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                     Log.e("", response.toString());
                     String myjsonstring=response.toString();
                     JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(myjsonstring);
                     JSONArray jsonarray= new JSONArray(jsono.getString("data"));        
                     JSONObject job = (JSONObject) jsonarray.get(0);
                     System.out.println("........."+job.getString("creator"));
                     String description = job.getString("description");
                     String endtime = job.getString("host");
                     String location = job.getString("location");
                     String name = job.getString("name");
                     String pic = job.getString("pic");
                     String picbig = job.getString("pic_big");
                     String piccover = job.getString("pic_cover");
                     String picsmall = job.getString("pic_small");
                     String picsquare = job.getString("pic_square");
                     String starttime = job.getString("start_time");
                     String timezone = job.getString("timezone");
                     System.out.println("........."+job.getString("venue"));
                     JSONObject jb1= new JSONObject(job.getString("venue"));
                     String lati =jb1.getString("latitude");
                     String longi =jb1.getString("longitude");
                     String city =jb1.getString("city");
                     String state =jb1.getString("state");
                     String country =jb1.getString("country");
                     String id =jb1.getString("id");
                     String street =jb1.getString("street");
                     String zip =jb1.getString("zip");
                }
    });

    Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
    return e;

}
```

This is the comoplete response I get:

```
06-29 20:48:46.808: E/LISA(10036): {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"data":[{"host":"Dave Luke","location":"Chipotle","pic_small":"https:\/\/fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\/hprofile-ak-ash3\/174629_204142299735343_644068191_t.jpg","pic_cover":null,"pic":"https:\/\/fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\/hprofile-ak-ash3\/174629_204142299735343_644068191_s.jpg","venue":{"id":398225253590019,"zip":"11375","street":"70-30 Austin St.","state":"NY","longitude":-73.845858172784,"latitude":40.720457257566,"country":"United States","city":"Forest Hills"},"creator":16300398,"timezone":null,"end_time":null,"pic_big":"https:\/\/fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\/hprofile-ak-ash3\/174629_204142299735343_644068191_n.jpg","description":"Discount txt Discount txt Discount txt\r\nShare\r\n-> Download the app at http:\/\/drinsco.altervista.org\/share.php?eid=204142299735343\r\n--> Login in your Facebook account to use your discount!\r\nasdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf adsf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdfqwer qwer qwer qwer qwer qwer qwer asdf qwer asfdqwerasdf wqer","name":"More Test Information","start_time":"2013-07-11T16:00:00+0200","pic_square":"https:\/\/fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net\/hprofile-ak-ash3\/174629_204142299735343_644068191_q.jpg"}]}}, error: null, isFromCache:false}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Gson

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Tutorial

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

Or You can parse the json as below

```
JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(myjsonstring);
JSONArray jsonarray= new JSONArray(jsono.getString("data")); 

JSONObject job = (JSONObject) jsonarray.get(0);
String creator = job.getString("creator"));
// similarly for description and others
System.out.println("........."+job.getString("venue"));
JSONObject jb1= new JSONObject(job.getString("venue")); 
String latitude = jb1.getString("latitude"));
// similarly for longitude and others.
```

Edit:

```
JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(myjsonstring);
JSONArray jsonarray= new JSONArray(jsono.getString("data"));        
JSONObject job = (JSONObject) jsonarray.get(0);
System.out.println("........."+job.getString("creator"));
String description = job.getString("description");
String endtime = job.getString("host");
String location = job.getString("location");
String name = job.getString("name");
String pic = job.getString("pic");
String picbig = job.getString("pic_big");
String piccover = job.getString("pic_cover");
String picsmall = job.getString("pic_small");
String picsquare = job.getString("pic_square");
String starttime = job.getString("start_time");
String timezone = job.getString("timezone");
System.out.println("........."+job.getString("venue"));
JSONObject jb1= new JSONObject(job.getString("venue"));
String lati =jb1.getString("latitude");
String longi =jb1.getString("longitude");
String city =jb1.getString("city");
String state =jb1.getString("state");
String country =jb1.getString("country");
String id =jb1.getString("id");
String street =jb1.getString("street");
String zip =jb1.getString("zip");
```

Comment: please I am sure this is pointing in the right direction, could you please elaborate a bit more? THANK YOU!!!!!

Comment: @LisaAnne tell me what pat i should elaborate?

Comment: Raghunandan it is not working, unfortunately...

Comment: what is not working for you? it works fine.

Comment: @LisaAnne tell me what is not working?

Comment: @LisaAnne check the edit entire parsing. i still don't know what is not working for you?

Comment: please see my edits in my answer

Comment: can you post the code instead of the pic. very difficult to spot the error

Comment: @LisaAnne the error is something not related to json parsing. the json parsing should work fine. tested works for me

Comment: JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(load()) please how does this work?

Comment: @LisaAnne that's a copy paste error. it should be json string.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32625/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-lisa-anne)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Google-Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Take a look to their example [here](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide). Maybe you can find something there useful.